# Extracting matching object from MatchQ

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to implement my own version of the `Coefficient` function in Mathematica, for learning purposes. This is what I wrote so far:

```
myCoefficient[fun_,var_,pow_] := Module[ {f,coeff},
    f[var] = Expand[fun];

    Map[ If[ MatchQ[#, a_ Power[var,pow] ], coeff=a] &, f[var]];
    Map[ If[ MatchQ[#, Power[var,pow] ], coeff=1] &, f[var]];

    Return[coeff];
]
```

My problem is that `If[ MatchQ[#, a_ Power[var,pow] ], coeff=a]` does not return what `a_` matches inside `MatchQ` but returns a literal 'a' instead.

How can I refer to what MatchQ matches?

Comment: If you are learning Mathematica, I would recommend http://mathematica.stackexchange.com instead of this site

Comment: I second that motion. The vast majority of the mathematica experts moved over there. A couple still haunt stackoverflow, but they're very rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to solve this problem was to use a substitution rule inside the `If` statement, like this:

```
Map[ If[ MatchQ[ #, a_. Power[var,pow] ], coeff = (# /. b_. Power[var,pow] -> b);] &, myexpr];
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do the kind of things you want is to use something like

```
If[ Length[matchedparts = Cases[ expr , pattern :> result]]>0 , use(matchedparts), do something else ]
```